# Unable to locate ADB in my newer android studio

Tags: android-studio

am on Android studio Arctic | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
i want test my program on my android device: LG-M700A (android version 8.1.0)

the problem is that android studio cant find my device and this is the Event log message:

> 10/01/2022 13:52  Adb connection Error:Une connexion existante a dû
> être fermée par l’hôte distant
>
> 13:52 Adb connection Error:Une connexion existante a dû être fermée
> par l’hôte distant
>
> 13:52 Adb connection Error:Une connexion existante a dû être fermée
> par l’hôte distant
>
> 13:52 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 13:52 * daemon started successfully
>
> 13:52 Adb connection Error:Une connexion existante a dû être fermée
> par l’hôte distant
>
> 13:52 Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
>
> 13:52 Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
>
> 13:52 Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
>
> 13:52 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 13:52 * daemon started successfully
>
> 13:52 Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

Comment: find it, the problem is on my smart phone, it give how you want link your phone:
TRANSMET files ?
transmet pictures...

or only charging.

select charging :D and all will done

Comment: You can do it from the developer tools as well. There's an option which says connect in charge mode. Also you can answer your own question and mark it as closed .:)

Comment: thank you, but where i can found the change mode in android studio ? and how i can mark my question as closed ?

Comment: Developer Tools> Allow Debugging in charge only mode. Turn that on.